# mongoose populate different database

Tags: mongoose-populate

I have two databases in my program. One for saving users and roles and one for the rest.

1) my model User has a reference to Roles. So I can populate roles by doing:

```js
User.find({}).populate('local.roles').sort({ email: 1 }).exec(function (err, users) { ...
```

This works perfect and I can get a user and his roles.

2) When I try to do the same, *but* with models that have a connection to another database, I get the infamous error:

"MissingSchemaError: schema hasn't been registered for model ..."

This is the way I code my models when they use a different connection:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// to define another mongoose connection 
var configScrwebDB = require('./../../config/scrwebDatabase.js');
var scrwebDBConnection = mongoose.createConnection(configScrwebDB.url);

var aseguradoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: { type: String },
    abreviatura: { type: String },
    rif: { type: String },
    direccion: { type: String }
});

module.exports = scrwebDBConnection.model('Asegurado', aseguradoSchema);
```

3) this is what I do to 'populate' some field in my query (and the one that fails with above error):

```js
    var query = Riesgo.find({ cia: filtroObject.ciaSeleccionada }); 
    query.populate('asegurado');
    query.sort("codigo"); 
    query.select("codigo fechaInicio estado moneda");



    query.exec(function (err, riesgos) { ...
```

Of course this is in another 'js' file; and I do my 'require', etc., in order to import my models; etc.

As I said before, I can populate when models use 'default' mongoose connection.

Any ideas how I should correct this will be appreciated ... Am I missing some obvious thing here?

Thanks and bye ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. You could use:

```
var query = Riesgo.find({ cia: filtroObject.ciaSeleccionada }); 
    query.populate('asegurado','fields to retrieve',User);// User need to be defined in the file as an variable that contents the User model defined.
    query.sort("codigo"); 
    query.select("codigo fechaInicio estado moneda");
```

[Refer link](https://github.com/mihai-chiorean/mongoose/commit/ef1209ec325aad364866fd82c816f87616e5a469)